# 2 UITableViews in a UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

Good afternoon

I am trying to create a scroll view that holds 2 tables. Code posted below, the tables are created without a problem and I am loading data into them on build but the 2nd table dosent seem to work, I can't scroll the data or select a cell. Any thoughts??

Thanks

```
- (void)setupPage
{
scrollView.delegate = self;    
[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

int initialXPos = 0;
int initialYPos = 10;

int arraycounter=0;
CGFloat cx = 0;
int aWidth = 0;

for (int j=0; j<3; j++) 
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(initialXPos, initialYPos, 320, 250)];
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(initialXPos, 0, 320, 250) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.tableView = tableView;

        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.tag = 1;        
        [tableView reloadData];

        [myView addSubview:tableView];
        [scrollView addSubview:myView];
    }

    if (j == 1)
    {
        UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(initialXPos, initialYPos, 320, 250)];
        myView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(initialXPos, 0, 320, 600) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.tableView = tableView;

        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.tag = 2;        
        [tableView reloadData];

        [myView1 addSubview:tableView];
        [scrollView addSubview:myView1];
    }

    initialXPos = initialXPos + 320 ;
    arraycounter=arraycounter+1;
    aWidth = aWidth + 320;
    cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
}
cx = aWidth;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = arraycounter;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use coordinates relative to myView1 when setting up the frame for tableView in case j==1.

Comment: it seems there is something wrong when i create the scrollview. I run the routine above on viewdidload but when i moved it to - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil it completely fails.

Comment: Ignore that last comment!, I have fixed the problem. I have removed the UIView and added the UITableView directly onto the scrollview and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this,

[scrollView addSubview:tableView1];

[scrollView addSubview:tableView2];

[myView addSubview:scrollView];

Means add first two table in scroll view then add scroll view into your main view
i solved this problem this way.